# how to get buttons output in panel in mat lab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button

In below MATLAB GUI button callback function, I want to direct the output of `imshow()` command onto a panel so that when I click the button then, after selecting the image, the image is shown in a specific panel.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=uigetfile(['*jpg'],'File Selector');
imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the handle to a `uiaxes`object. You can create a new `uifigure` with the `uiaxes`, if needed, or use the handle to an existing `uiaxes`, and then pass the handle to the callback function.

```
fig=uifigure();
ax=uiaxes(fig);

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles,ax)
image=uigetfile(['*jpg'],'File Selector');
imshow(ax,image)
```